# Linux Stripes on Screen

Tags: bios, amd-graphics, screen-lock, radeon, amdgpu

I was using Linux Mint 21.1. My sreen was frozen yesterday and I restarted it. After restart, the computer gives me `kfd kfd amdgpu oland not supported in kfd error` on black screen.

I tried to open compatibility mode and fix with installing amdgpu drivers but didn't work. I couldn't fresh Linux Mint install because when I try to install from usb, I couldn't see graphical screen.

There just colorful squares and stripes. So I decided to install Debian 12. Everything went good until end of install. When I open my computer I saw screens below. First one is login screen second one is desktop screen.

I think my GPU is broken but I would like to hear from you who know or see something like that.

GPU: AMD R7 250 OS: Linux Mint, Debian 12

---

**Update:**
I resetted the bios and now see `radeon: failed initializing UVD (-1).`

---

**Update:**
When I try to boot with Linux Mint 21.1 USB, screen still broken and half of the screen visible.
[image: login_screen]
[image: desktop]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.